# Set PRAGMA after database connection in Kysely

Tags: node.js, sqlite, kysely

I want to run `PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL` on my database connection as soon as it is connected using the [Kysely library](https://kysely.dev/).

Here's what I've tried:

```js
const dialect = new SqliteDialect({
    database: new SQLite(":memory:"),
    onCreateConnection: async connnection => {
        const pragmaQuery = sql<string>`PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL`;
        connection.executeQuery(pragmaQuery.compile());
    },
});
```

However, `pragmaQuery.compile()` [requires a reference to the database](https://kysely.dev/docs/recipes/splitting-build-compile-and-execute-code#compile-a-query), which I don't have in this function's scope. (I instantiate `db` below, which needs `dialect` as an argument.)

I'm having trouble using the [DatabaseConnection interface](https://kysely-org.github.io/kysely-apidoc/interfaces/DatabaseConnection.html), as it has very few callable methods.

Answer (score 0):

Option A (execute raw SQL via Kysely):

```
const dialect = new SqliteDialect({
    database: new SQLite(":memory:")
});

export const db = new Kysely<Database>({
    dialect
})

sql`PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL`.execute(db)
```

Option B (execute SQL directly on SQLite instance):

```
const sqlite = new SQLite(":memory:")
const dialect = new SqliteDialect({
    database: sqlite
});

sqlite.exec('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL')
```

Comment: I don't have a reference to `db`; I need to run this `onCreateConnection`